# Is it possible to auto focus on a table row after data is retrieved from a controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to automatically add focus to the first row of a table after a search as I have functionality to allow arrow key navigation to move up/down a table of results.

I have a value($scope.firstItem) that I'm setting in a controller after some search results have been retrieved. So I can setup a $watch function and then trigger some code in a directive.

In my controller:

```
...
$scope.firstItem = data[0];
....
```

In a directive I have:

```
module.exports = function(){

    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('$parent.firstItem', function(oldValue, newValue){
            var firstTableRow = element[0].children[0].children[0];

            if ( firstTableRow !== undefined ) {
                firstTableRow.classList.add('info');
                firstTableRow.focus(); // Todo: Not focusing, need to find out why
            }
        });
    };
};
```

The $watch function is working and the class of 'info' is being added to the first row, which proves the context is correct, but focus() is not working.

Instead of using focus() I've also tried:

```
firstTableRow.trigger('click');
```

But I get an error saying [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress. Which I guess is because Angular hasn't finished doing whatever its doing and can't create the event.

Any ideas what do I need to do to get this working? Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is it even possible to automatically focus on a table row?

EDIT: I have tried moving the focus to other elements on the page(another textbox) and this worked fine. It just doesn't want to focus on the table row.

EDIT2: I tried adding a timeout function and this is now working and focusing on the table although this is obviously not reliable at all! But it does indicate that something else is going on and explains why my original code wasn't working. Is there an event I can hook onto once Angular finishes doing whatever it's doing to stop me executing the focus method?

```
if ( firstTableRow !== undefined ) {
     firstTableRow.classList.add('info');
     element.focus(); // Todo: Not focusing, need to find out why

     setTimeout(function(){
         console.log("FOCUS");
         element.focus();
     }, 500);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to focus on the first td in the cell of the first row? You are also only allowed one autofocus per page and if your application is a single page app, you may be fighting with an auto focus elsewhere

Comment: There shouldn't be an autofocus on the page. There was one but I removed it but it still doesn't work. I've also tried focusing on the first table cell in the row but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I have tried moving the focus to other elements on the page(another textbox) and this worked fine. It just doesn't want to focus on the table row.